# C# Call a function when a second key is pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, event-handling

I'm lost calling a function when a second key is pressed. I have used KeyDown event for my buttons. And that KeyDown will call a function that will check that button. My problem is after checking that button, the user must press another Enter Key or Spacebar to go on the next data.

This is for my radiobutton1 KeyDown event

```
private void btn1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        btn1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        checkAns(btn1.Text, btn1);
    }
```

This is my checkAns function that will check the selected button

```
private void checkAns (string ansText, RadioButton rdo)
    {
        var row = dTable.Rows[currentRow];
        var ans = row["ANSWER"].ToString();
        if (ansText == ans)
        {
            rdo.BackColor = Color.Green;
            correctAdd();
            //MessageBox.Show("Correct");
        }
        else
        {
            rdo.BackColor = Color.Red;
            wrongAdd();
            //MessageBox.Show("Wrong. Answer is" + " \n " + ans);
        }
        nextEnter (------); //Here I'm not sure how to call the another keydown/keypress event or value of the enter key
    }
```

This is my nextEnter function

```
private void nextEnter(------) //Also at this part.
    {
        if (------ == Keys.Enter) //And here.
        currentRow++;
        currentNo++;
        remain--;
        nextRow();
    }
```

Comment: You could pass the `KeyCode` property of your `KeyEventArgs` from `btn1_KeyDown` to `checkAns` and further on to `nextEnter`.

Comment: @MetaColon, sorry i dont get it. please do correct me. the key code(enter) , that is the object? to checkans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this problem by having the form increment a variable during enter keydown event.

```
private void frmTest_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            entCount++;
        }
    }
```

and use if statement when entCount == 2, show the next data and reset the entCount to 0.

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate what I meant in my comment:

You could pass the `KeyCode` property of your `KeyEventArgs` from `btn1_KeyDown`

```
private void btn1_KeyDown (object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    btn1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    checkAns (btn1.Text, btn1, e.KeyCode);
}
```

to `checkAns`

```
private void checkAns (string ansText, RadioButton rdo, Keys pressedKey)
{
    var row = dTable.Rows [currentRow];
    var ans = row ["ANSWER"].ToString ();
    if (ansText == ans)
    {
        rdo.BackColor = Color.Green;
        correctAdd ();
        //MessageBox.Show("Correct");
    }
    else
    {
        rdo.BackColor = Color.Red;
        wrongAdd ();
        //MessageBox.Show("Wrong. Answer is" + " \n " + ans);
    }
    nextEnter (pressedKey); //Here I'm not sure how to call the another keydown/keypress event or value of the enter key
}
```

And further on to `nextEnter`:

```
private void nextEnter (Keys key) //Also at this part.
{
    if (key == Keys.Enter) //And here.
    currentRow++;
    currentNo++;
    remain--;
    nextRow ();
}
```

Tell me if I misunderstood anything, you need further help or my solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: the behavior is still the same. hitting enter key once. will move on to the next data.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your question - in that behaviour you'll indeed have to solve it with a counter.